How to fix „error:unknown filesystem.“? Grub rescue
I was trying to boot into Linux and suddenly got this error message:
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode…
grub rescue>

I tried following commands:
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal

But the last one gave me this error:
error: invalid sector size 65535
I tried searching it up but nothing helped. How can I fix it or how can I boot normally again in Linux.
